# I am trying to open Omni-Notes Open source project but keep getting error

Tags: android

The error on gradle sync Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.5.6!

here is a screenshot
http://prntscr.com/755pp7

Please let me know what else you need !

pply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.feio.android.omninotes"
    minSdkVersion project.MIN_SDK
    targetSdkVersion project.TARGET_SDK
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(
                        output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
            }
        }
    }
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code and your `build.gradle`. Don't post screen shots when you can post code.

Comment: I added the first part

Comment: I added the first part and here is the second part http://prntscr.com/756bwk I could not upload it here because some error stackoverflow does not let me submit the code

Comment: I still did not get a reply

Comment: Post the error and both of your `build.gradle` files. How can I debug something I cannot see?

Comment: Error :Failed to  reslove:com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.5.6 . I cannot upload the full one because stack flow does not allow me to do this . The first part of the gradle is uploaded in the question and second part is in this link of the screenshot of a code http://prntscr.com/756bwk

Comment: For the last time. Post both of your `build.gradle` files and the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

MaterialDialog library updated to version 0.7.4.1.In build.gradle(Module:app) file, 
replace

> compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.5.6'

by

> compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.4.1'